# How get the file name in the directory in winCE? (C#)

Tags: c#, window, windows-ce

My application is running on the winCE platform and needs to search the file when it initialized, but it seems winCE is very different from windows.

## Step1. Get the current directory

So first, I am using a code to get a directory:

`string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase.ToString()) + "\\";`

The path is "\Program Files\SmartDeviceProject1\".
But when I use `console.write` it shows "\Program Files\SmartDeviceProject1\". So it missed "\"

## Step2. Trying to get all the file name in the path

`FileInfo[] fileinfo = dir.GetFiles();`

## Step3. Use a loop and IF to identify the file exist or not.

## Here is some code.

```cs
string filename = "bridgetool";
            // string path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(); // This is not working in winCE
            // Get the current path
            string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase.ToString()) + "\\";
            Console.Write(path);
            DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(path);
            FileInfo[] fileinfo = dir.GetFiles();
            foreach (FileInfo file in fileinfo)
            {
                if (filename == file.ToString())
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            Console.Write("Cannot find");
            return false;
```

I got the right current path but the problem is that the path I get and path I printed out is different. I am not sure if it is a problem.

Is there any way to search the file name in the specific path?

Comment: Windows CE does not have the concept of a current directory, hence why GetCurrentDirectory is not supported.
What is the path you're getting, and what is the path that gets printed? The two paths in the question are identical.

Comment: Yes. `GetCurrentDirectory` does not support but I use GetDirectoryName to get the exact address, which prints out "\Program Files\SmartDeviceProject1" on the winCE command port. <br>Then I want to open a File every time I launch the application so I use a `foreach` search here but it always give a "Cannot find" even the file is exist.

Comment: thanks for your help and I found where the fault is. I should not use `file.ToString()`. Instead, just use `file` in my `if` judgment.